# CKeditor5 caret keeps focusing left but I want it after the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor5

I am trying to code it so that there is a click outside of ckeditor to insert text into the editor. I am using below.

```js
if (editorInstance) {
    editorInstance.model.change(writer => {
        writer.insertText(
            ` ${$(this).find('td:last').text()} `, 
            editorInstance.model.document.selection.getLastPosition(), 
            'end'
        );
    });
}

const text = $('.ck-content').text();
$('.ck-content').val('').focus().text(text);
```

If I type into the editor first then click to insert, everything is fine. If I just click then the caret position doesn't go to the end of the text. Is there an easy solution to move the text cursor to the end of the text in for ckeditor5?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself, it is as below.

```
editorInstance.setData('TEXT TO SET');
editorInstance.model.change( writer => {
    writer.setSelection( writer.createPositionAt( editorInstance.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' ));
});
```

It is important here to first set the text and then move the caret after.
I hope that will help anybody who faces the same issue in the future.